# Get notified when a program adds itself to autostart?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, autostart

I would like to get notified when a program adds itself to the Startup / Autostart list, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Nice question, that would be really useful. There are programs like Windows 8 Task Manager where you can see what programs are autostarting and disable them or Autoruns which shows you everything that is autostarting when you turn on your OS. But they do not notify you when new programs or services are added to autostart.

Comment: this is not possible in Windows 8. You can code a tool yourself which monitors the several locations where tools can be run at startup. Or you can ask Mark Russinovich (http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/contact.aspx) if he can add this to AutoRuns.

Comment: This is possible. In fact, I remember that Spybot: Search 'N Destroy used to have (probably still does) a monitoring component that'd ask for your permission before any application modified the registry to add itself to startup

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a component in [Spybot 1.6](http://www.safer-networking.org/mirrors16/) called [TeaTimer](http://www.safer-networking.org/faq_category/teatimer/).

From the Spybot website:

```
TeaTimer detects when something wants to change some critical registry keys.

TeaTimer can protect you against such changes again giving you an option: You can either Allow or Deny the
change.

The TeaTimer is always running in the
background.
```

However this feature was replaced by Live Protection in the newer version of the malware scanner, which I haven't used and hence am not sure monitors registry changes. This is what Spybot FAQ [says about Live Protection](http://www.safer-networking.org/faq/is-there-any-replacement-for-teatimer-resident/):

```
With each paid Spybot 2 Edition there is the new Live Protection available. This Live Protection monitors every process created or running on your system and scans each process.

Malicious processes are blocked even before they start. If you have another antivirus engine running you can choose to disable Live Protection.

Live Protection allows the user to choose to run or suppress any starting process.
```